# Keyboard language change and very bad performance when booting battery

Tags: boot, nvidia, keyboard-layout, battery, performance

I encounter a very weird behaviour when booting Ubuntu 20.04 in battery mode.
I automount a few encrypted partitions (some from internal, some external drive) via crypttab using Veracrypt. Up until the decryption is done, everything seems rather normal. But then when typing the password at the Ubuntu login screen, the first weird thing is happening: Instead of my usual German QWERTZ keyboard layout, I am encountering a keyboard change to English QWERTY layout (noticed since my password contains "z").
After login, next weird thing: It takes super long to actually load the desktop and even after loading the desktop, Ubuntu is super unreactive/slow.

On my machine, I have a dual boot (Ubuntu/Windows) and in Windows I do not have this problem.

Does anyone have an idea what might be the problem here?

Some additional information that might be helpful:

- OS: Ubuntu 20.04.6 LTS
- kernel: 5.15.0-56-generic
- GPU: NVIDIA GeForce RTX 3070 mobile

  - Driver Version: 545.23.06
- CPU: Intel i7-11800H

Some errors/fails are showing in `dmesg` but I could not relate them to the problem

```
[    1.325308] i801_smbus 0000:00:1f.4: SMBus using PCI interrupt
[    9.477756] EXT4-fs (nvme0n1p5): re-mounted. Opts: errors=remount-ro. Quota mode: none.
[    9.588048] intel-hid INTC1051:00: failed to read mode
[    9.775660] thermal thermal_zone7: failed to read out thermal zone (-61)
[   11.542769] ucsi_acpi USBC000:00: UCSI_GET_PDOS failed (-95)
[   13.780550] ucsi_acpi USBC000:00: con2: failed to register alt modes
[   13.828469] ucsi_acpi USBC000:00: PPM init failed (-110)
[   23.776617] snd_hda_codec_realtek ehdaudio0D0: ASoC: error at snd_soc_dai_startup on Digital Codec DAI: -22
[   23.776619]  Digital Playback and Capture: soc_pcm_open() failed (-22)
[   23.776620]  HDA Digital: ASoC: dpcm_be_dai_startup() failed at Digital Playback and Capture (-22)
[   23.776621]  HDA Digital: dpcm_fe_dai_startup() failed (-22)
[   23.776664] snd_hda_codec_realtek ehdaudio0D0: ASoC: error at snd_soc_dai_startup on Digital Codec DAI: -22
[   23.776665]  Digital Playback and Capture: soc_pcm_open() failed (-22)
[   23.776665]  HDA Digital: ASoC: dpcm_be_dai_startup() failed at Digital Playback and Capture (-22)
[   23.776666]  HDA Digital: dpcm_fe_dai_startup() failed (-22)
[   24.891035] evdi: [W] evdi_painter_connect_ioctl:992 (card2)(pid=5578) disconnect failed
[   24.891056] evdi: [W] evdi_painter_connect_ioctl:992 (card3)(pid=5578) disconnect failed
[   24.891071] evdi: [W] evdi_painter_connect_ioctl:992 (card4)(pid=5578) disconnect failed
[   24.891085] evdi: [W] evdi_painter_connect_ioctl:992 (card5)(pid=5578) disconnect failed
[   39.604612] CIFS: VFS: cifs_mount failed w/return code = -115
[   61.975171] snd_hda_codec_realtek ehdaudio0D0: ASoC: error at snd_soc_dai_startup on Digital Codec DAI: -22
[   61.975173]  Digital Playback and Capture: soc_pcm_open() failed (-22)
[   61.975174]  HDA Digital: ASoC: dpcm_be_dai_startup() failed at Digital Playback and Capture (-22)
[   61.975175]  HDA Digital: dpcm_fe_dai_startup() failed (-22)
[   61.975207] snd_hda_codec_realtek ehdaudio0D0: ASoC: error at snd_soc_dai_startup on Digital Codec DAI: -22
[   61.975208]  Digital Playback and Capture: soc_pcm_open() failed (-22)
[   61.975209]  HDA Digital: ASoC: dpcm_be_dai_startup() failed at Digital Playback and Capture (-22)
[   61.975210]  HDA Digital: dpcm_fe_dai_startup() failed (-22)
[   67.261944] evdi: [W] evdi_painter_connect_ioctl:992 (card2)(pid=9586) disconnect failed
[   67.261975] evdi: [W] evdi_painter_connect_ioctl:992 (card3)(pid=9586) disconnect failed
[   67.261984] evdi: [W] evdi_painter_connect_ioctl:992 (card4)(pid=9586) disconnect failed
[   67.261994] evdi: [W] evdi_painter_connect_ioctl:992 (card5)(pid=9586) disconnect failed
```

Please let me know if there are any additional information I can provide to help solve this problem.